# How to run command on container startup, and keep container running after command is done?

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I have a `Dockerfile`, which is meant to use `script1`, like so:

```
# Pull from Debian
FROM debian
    
# Update apt and install dependencies
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install wget curl
    
# Download script1.sh
RUN wget -O ./script1.sh https://example.com
    
# Make script1.sh executable
RUN chmod +x ./script1.sh
```

Currently, I can:

1. Build this Dockerfile into an image
2. Run said image in a container
3. Open a CLI in said container, and run `script1` manually (with `bash ./script1.sh`)
4. The script runs, and the container stays open.

However, I'd like to automatically run this script on container startup.

So I tried to change my `Dockerfile` to this:

```
# Pull from Debian
FROM debian

# Update apt and install dependencies
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install wget curl

# Download script1.sh
RUN wget -O ./script1.sh https://example.com

# Make script1.sh executable
RUN chmod +x ./script1.sh

# Run script1.sh on startup
CMD bash ./script1.sh
```

However, when I do this, the container only stays open for a little bit, and then exits right away.

I suspect it exits as soon as `script1` is done...

I also tried `ENTRYPOINT`, without much success.

Why does my container stay open if I open a CLI and run the script manually, but doesn't stay open if I try to automatically run it at startup?

And how can I run the script automatically on container startup, and keep the container from exiting right away?

Comment: When you say "the container stays open", what's the process it should be running?  Or if there's not a specific process, why is the container itself important?  ("When I run `ls`, how do I keep the process from exiting after it writes its directory listing?")

Comment: I think you should provide script1.sh or at least something that exemplifies what it does.

Answer (score 1):

An old Docker (v2) tricks to prevent premature container closing consisted in letting run an "infinite" loop command in it, such as:

```
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: I tried `CMD bash ./script1.sh && tail -f /dev/null`, but it didn't work.
How should I use this command?

Comment: Dockerfile: ```FROM debian

CMD ls /usr && tail -f /dev/null
```

Build: ```docker build -t temp .```

Run ```docker run --rm temp``` <-- lists the contents of /usr inside the container then keeps running without doing anything.

Comment: @antoniopgs Presumably, your script exits with a non-zero exit code. Therefore, the tail command is not executed (because && short-circuits if the first process fails).